# pyqt Snap builds successful, fails to run

Tags: python, snap

I built a snap using python3 plugin. It should open a PyQt5 app. The snap built with no problem, but after the snap is installed, calling the installed python script in command line fails with the error below.

My *snapcraft.yaml*

```
name: pyqthelloworld
version: 0.1.0
summary: pyqt hello world
description: |
 a pyqt5 python3 hello world test

confinement: strict

apps:
  pyqthelloworld:
    command: pyqthelloworld

parts:
  pyqthelloworld:
    plugin: python3
    source: git://github.com/ericoporto/pyqthelloworld
    source-type: git
    stage-packages:
      - python3-pyqt5
      - libc-bin
      - locales
```

I built and installed using the commands below

```
snapcraft stage
snapcraft snap
sudo snap install pyqthelloworld_0.1.0_amd64.snap
```

In command line

```
$ pyqthelloworld

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fb8fc0ff700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What's wrong? And how do I debug similar errors in snaps?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

Edit: checking if encodings is there (is this correct?)

```
user@pc:~/git/pyqthelloworld/snap$ find . -iname encodings
./prime/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings
./parts/pyqthelloworld/install/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings
./stage/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings
```

Edit2: I am now getting (snapcraft 2.15.1):

```
$ pyqthelloworld 
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Just to clarify, no changes, just a newer snapcraft on the same (and updated) Ubuntu 16.04 computer.

Edit3:

Now I added a [snap folder](https://github.com/ericoporto/pyqthelloworld/tree/master/snap), where I am keeping the snapcraft.yaml (which is now a little different than the one in the beginning of this question!) and a little wrapper to deal with the locale error - which I don't think should be needed.

Now when I run the command (pyqthelloworld) for the installed snap I am getting:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1576411

Comment: I believe, it already passed thought as I have make a look on git repository. Could set correct answer or write new answer, if you remember the case,  if is quiet old, 4 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

There are currently two bugs related to snaps which block this, both are in the works to be fixed though:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1576411
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapcraft/+bug/1576282

Can you check the contents of your snap and see if there are any `encodings` modules shipped?

Comment: I didn't knew how to proper check, so I added local find output on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were most likely a victim of the hashbang problem, recent versions of snapcraft should solve this, if not one other option is to use a relative path in `command` so that essentially `command` is `command: usr/bin/pyqthelloworld`

Comment: Hey, I used a tiny wrapper to win the locale error, but am stuck again, Qt is throwing a new error now.